# double click not working in protractor type script

Tags: typescript, selenium, protractor

Double click not working.

**html :**

```
<div class="dhx_scale_hour" style="height: 851px; width: 50px;">
   <div style="height:72px;line-height:30px;">::before "06:00 pm"/div>
   <div style="height:72px;line-height:30px;">::before "06:05 pm"</div>
   <div style="height:72px;line-height:30px;">::before "06:10 pm"</div>
   <div style="height:72px;line-height:30px;">::before "06:15 pm"</div>
   <div style="height:72px;line-height:30px;">::before "06:20 pm"</div>
   <div style="height:72px;line-height:30px;">::before "06:25 pm"</div>
   <div style="height:72px;line-height:30px;">::before "06:30 pm"</div>
   <div style="height:72px;line-height:30px;">::before "06:35 pm"</div>
   <div style="height:72px;line-height:30px;">::before "06:40 pm"</div>
   <div style="height:72px;line-height:30px;">::before "06:45 pm"</div>
   <div style="height:72px;line-height:30px;">::before "06:50 pm"</div>
   <div style="height:72px;line-height:30px;">::before "06:55 pm"</div>
</div>
```

**Protractor Type Script :**

```
browser.actions().doubleClick(element(by.xpath('//*[@id="appointmentSchedulerControl"]/div[3]/div[7]/div[19]/div[1]'))).perform();
```

don't get any of the error just it will not double click on specified elements.

Comment: Are you going to select any value from dropdown?

Comment: Are you sure it is locating the element correctly?

Comment: @kunduk no there is no drop down as it is side panel which contains time. And I want to double click on it

Comment: @KunduK how can i create xpath for that ?

Answer (score 0):

`doubleclick()` and `perform()` both returns the promise.
You have to make sure your code includes one of the following way.

1. Use async/await.
2. Chain thenables.

For option 2 see the following:

```
perform().then( function () { 
       browser.sleep(1000); // or you can write if there is some validation here
})
```

Comment: What could be the suggested xpath. ?

Comment: Share code snippet written before this line                                                                                    
browser.actions().doubleClick(element(by.xpath('//*[@id="appointmentSchedulerControl"]/div[3]/div[7]/div[19]/div[1]'))).perform();